# Существуют abstract class, public class, private class

Tags: php

А когда и в каких случаях их надо применять ? И в чём их разница ? 
И как понять абстрактный class ? 
Как понять публичный class ?
И особенно приватный в каких случаях их применяют ?
Не где учится приходится спрашивать

Comment: По-моему не совсем верно, существует abstract class, final class, а модификаторы public, private и protected используются уже для переменных и методов класса?

Comment: во , я так и думал что я ни верно поставил вопрос , спасибо что поправили , и в каких случях их применяют , и плиз в ответ это включите , мне же надо вас отметить Лучшим

Comment: только если можно подробно , я не понимаю что вообще это значит , на http://php.net есть мануал но там только для тех кто уже прошёл обучение и для тех кто знает технический английский язык а я только разговорный т.е классический с трудом понимаю

Comment: На php.net есть и русский перевод http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.php - он немного отстает по актуальности от английского, но в целом довольно хороший.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

У вас путаница в терминологии.

Классы в PHP бывают `abstract` и `final` - это верно, а вот `public`, `protected`, `private` - это области видимости методов и свойств класса.

**abstract**

Абстрактный класс, это класс, экземпляр которого нельзя создать, интерпретатор выдаст в этом случае ошибку. Если класс содержит хотя бы один абстрактный метод, то класс целиком должен быть объявлен как абстрактный:

```
abstract class A {
}

$a = new A();
```

Результат:

```
Fatal error: Cannot instantiate abstract class A in test.php on line 6
```

Такой класс нужно переопределить, реализовать его абстрактные методы, если они есть, в потомках и потом создавать экземпляры. Подробнее в мануале : [абстрактные классы](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.abstract.php) (все ссылки на русскую версию руководства).

**final**

> PHP 5 представляет ключевое слово final, разместив которое перед
>   объявлениями методов класса, можно предотвратить их переопределение в
>   дочерних классах.

Другими словами, `final` класс нельзя расширить, а `final` метод нельзя переопределить. Подробнее в мануале: [ключевое слово "final"](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.final.php).

```
final class F {
}

class FromF extends F {
}

Fatal error: Class FromF may not inherit from final class (F) in test.php on line 7
```

**public, private, protected**

Всё это модификаторы областей видимости для методов и свойств классов.

`public` - используется, если свойство или метод должны быть доступны везде: в самом классе, в его потомках, а также доступны извне.

`private` -

> ограничивает область видимости так, что только класс, где объявлен сам
>   элемент, имеет к нему доступ.

`protected` -

> разрешает доступ наследуемым и родительским классам.

Подробнее в мануале: [области видимости](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.visibility.php).

Также, раз вы задаете такой вопрос, вам лучше начать с основ: [ООП основы](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.basic.php), [классы и объекты в PHP](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.php).

Answer (score 3):

Я бы добавил, что:
1) Абстрактный класс (в PHP) не обязан содержать абстрактные свойства и методы, хотя, как правило, так и делают.
2) Т.к. в PHP нет внутренниx (вложенных) классов, модификаторы области видимости классов не имеют смысла и их нет. В Яве они например есть. Они определяют видимость вложенных классов вне класса, в котором они определены.

Помечая класс как абстрактный Вы делаете невозможным создание экземпляра этого класса, что защищает программу от ошибок.

Помечая методы как абстрактные вы можете их использовать в теле абстрактного класса без реализации. (Только объявив с модификатором abstract).
Например реализовать в классе метод сортировки используя абстрактный метод сравнения compare(a,b) в то время как реализация самого метода сравнения будет в дочерних классах.

Answer (score 1):

По-моему не совсем верно, существует `abstract,`final` классы, а модификаторы public, private и protected используются уже для переменных и методов класса.

Абстрактным `abstract` помечают класс, который в своем составе содержит абстрактные методы, т.е. классы без реализации и тоже помеченные ключевым словом `abstract`. Для таких классов нельзя создать объект, от них только наследуют другие классы. Причем все наследники обязаны предоставить реализацию абстрактных классов, в противном случае PHP выдаст сообщение об ошибке.

Константный класс `final` решает другую задачу, от классов, помеченных таким ключевым словом нельзя наследовать другие классы. Этот класс завершен и больше не подлежит расширению.

Методы и члены класса, помеченные модификатором доступа `public`, доступны для вызова как внутри класса, так и из вне.

Методы и члены класса, помеченные модификатором `private`, доступны только внутри класса, для методов класса, из вне к ним обратиться нельзя.

Методы и члены класса, помеченные модификатором `protected` похоже на `private`, но дополнительно доступны всем наследникам класса.

Comment: cheops  простите ответ выше очень развёрнутый , но страницу я сохранил как pdf и это будет моя подсказка , спс

Comment: @LenovoID, все нормально, выбирайте лучший ответ, SO для этого и предназначен :)